# How do I found out the Host/Port when connecting to SAP HANA using python PyHDB

Tags: python, hana

I'm trying to connect to a SAP HANA database, but I don't know where to find the `host` or `port` attributes for `pyhdb.connect()`

Test Code Below

```
import pyhdb

connection = pyhdb.connect(
    host="",
    port="",
    user="exampleusername",
    password="examplepassword"
)

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT 'Hello Python World'")
cursor.fetchone()

connection.close()
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

`HOST`,`PORT` and `DATABASENAME` are part of the SAP HANA logon information, forming the logical address of the database.

There is no way to "find out" the values for those parameters if you don't control the database **except for that somebody who does, tells you.**

The `HOST` in this scenario is the network host address for the system where the HANA database runs on. `PORT` depends on the actual installation of the database system and `DATABASENAME` is the logical name of the database, again something that can be freely chosen by the database administrator.

Using the SAP HANA Express Edition Virtual Machine as an example:
`HOST` would be `hxehost` (or the IP address that the VM is reachable at).
`PORT` is `39015` following the `3xx15` pattern where `xx` is the **instance number** of the system, `90` in this instance.
`DATABASENAME` finally is `HXE` (**H**ANA E**x**press **E**dition).