# How to specifies database name in pyhdb

Tags: python, hana

```
import pyhdb
connect = pyhdb.connect(
    host="example.com",
    port=30015,
    user="user",
    password="secret"
)
```

From the official explanation
Pyhdb only gives four parameters. Without the parameter database name, I can't understand how the system knows which database you want to connect to in this case?

And when i connect in this way, Program error："pyhdb.exceptions.DatabaseError: authentication failed",
it looks like my password is wrong, so i let friends use JAVA(jdbc) to connect with four parameters,
it failed too, but if he add database name, it worked! so my parameters is right , and question is how to specify database name in pyhdb?

Or there are other ways to connect to Hana, Thankyou!

Comment: Does this help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60759226/how-do-i-found-out-the-host-port-when-connecting-to-sap-hana-using-python-pyhdb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the `__init__.py` file of the **pyhdb** package shows that `DATABASENAME` is **not** supported when creating a connection:

```
[...]    
def connect(host, port, user, password, autocommit=False):
    conn = Connection(host, port, user, password, autocommit)
    conn.connect()
    return conn
[...]
```

The good news here is that **pyhdb** is not what you should be using to connect to HANA anyhow as it is the old and unsupported client library.

Use **hdbcli** instead as described in the [documentation](https://help.sap.com/viewer/f1b440ded6144a54ada97ff95dac7adf/2.5/en-US/f3b8fabf34324302b123297cdbe710f0.html).

With **hdbcli** it's no problem at all to use the `DATABASENAME`:

```
from hdbcli import dbapi

connection =dbapi.connect(address="hxehost", port=39013, databasename="HXE", user="xxxxx", password="xxxxx")

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT 'Hello, Python world' FROM DUMMY")

print(cursor.fetchone())

connection.close()
```